# Keras (R) error while executing fit generator

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network

I have an error using fit_generator in R...
here's my code..`

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_conv_2d(32, c(3,3), input_shape = c(64, 64, 3)) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(32, c(3, 3)) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(128) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%
  layer_dense(128) %>%
  layer_activation("relu") %>%
  layer_dense(2) %>%
  layer_activation("softmax")

opt <- optimizer_adam(lr = 0.001, decay = 1e-6)

model %>%
  compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics = "accuracy")

train_gen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  shear_range = 0.2,
                                  zoom_range = 0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip = T)

test_gen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1./255)

train_set = train_gen$flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                          target_size = c(64, 64),
                                          class_mode = "categorical")

test_set = test_gen$flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                        target_size = c(64, 64),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

model$fit_generator(train_set,
                    steps_per_epoch = 50,
                    epochs = 10)
```

> Error:
>       Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>         StopIteration: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

If I put validation set it has another error too 
bool(validation_data). Float error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult help you without a minimal reproducible example.

I am guessing you get this error when you are trying to run

```
train_set = train_gen$flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                          target_size = c(64, 64),
                                          class_mode = "categorical")
```

Here you are calling the python function yourself using `reticulate` and not a `keras` (the R package) wrapper. That might work, but you have to be more explicit about the type and use `target_size = as.integer(c(64, 64))`, since python expects an integer.

Alternatively, I would suggest looking into the `flow_images_from_directory()` function included in the `keras` package.

---

The same goes for

```
model$fit_generator(train_set,
                    steps_per_epoch = 50,
                    epochs = 10)
```

I'd suggest looking into

```
model %>% 
  fit_generator()
```

instead, which is part of the `keras` package.

Comment: It worked ... But I've got a new error now .. CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED

Comment: Try using the `keras` functions I mentioned instead (`flow_images_from_directory()` and `model %>% fit_generator()`)

Comment: I used it flow_images_from_directory inside model%>% fit_generator() after that I got this new error CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED seems like Cuda problem but Keras works in Python though..